# pgfplots bar plot with only y coordinate from file

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a file that looks like this:

```
bytes    op1        op2        op3             
16       18.28      21.32      21.27
```

I would like now to make a simple pgfplots bar using the data from that file, having three bars distributed over the axis area using those three data points as y values, and I should be able to specify running x values, e.g. it would plot bars for coordinates {(0, 18.28), (1, 21.32), (2, 21.27)}.

How could I obtain this? The closest I get is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={Pressure},
            grid,
            ybar
        ]
        \addplot table [y index=1] {data/data.dat};
        \addplot table [y index=2] {data/data.dat};
        \addplot table [y index=3] {data/data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but this does not allow me to specify the x coordinates.

Comment: You can use `\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=1] {data/data.dat};`

Comment: @Jake an answer, sir?

Comment: Hi @Jake, sadly that does not seem to work because there is only 1 row per column so they all get x=0.

Comment: @MartinLauridsen: Ah yes, sorry, in this case you should use `\addplot table [x expr=0, y index=1] {data/data.dat};`, `\addplot table [x expr=1, y index=2] {data/data.dat};`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you @Jake. Bonus Q: What if the table had had another row, and I wanted to only bar plot one of the rows, but using my own x values as you said? Also, you wanna answer so I can give credit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.